# how to gomock a server streaming grpc method?

Tags: go, grpc, gomock

I tried using the following code but the client hangs and never receives from the mock server.
I thought this part: `Do(rs.EXPECT().Send(&proto.Response{Result: "steve"})`would make the mock server response to the client, it never worked out.

For a server-streaming grpc mock, a typical approach like:

```
mockServer.EXPECT().FetchResponse(&proto.Request{Id: 123}, rs).Times(1).Return(...)
```

doesn't work, the return value is expected to be an error, not a streaming message.

Could someone with a kind heart please explain how this problem should be handled properly?

## Code

```
func Test_Streaming(t *testing.T) {
    // create listiner
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50005")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    // create grpc server
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    c := gomock.NewController(t)
    mockServer := mock_proto.NewMockStreamServiceServer(c)
    proto.RegisterStreamServiceServer(s, mockServer)

    go func() {
        log.Println("start server")
        // and start...
        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
        }
    }()
    rs := mock_proto.NewMockStreamService_FetchResponseServer(c)
    mockServer.EXPECT().FetchResponse(&proto.Request{Id: 123}, rs).Times(1).Do(rs.EXPECT().Send(&proto.Response{Result: "steve"}))
    // client call FetchResponse
    ClientConnect()
}
```

Comment: Do you necessarily have to mock or you are just looking for a way to test your services?

Comment: @ClémentJean I am looking for a way to test my server side streaming GRPC services, for unary GRPC methods, gomock work pretty well, since I'm able to set the return grpc response. It doesn't work out for server streaming GRPC method.

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't mock the server. You should instantiate a real one in memory (without port, ...). This can be done with the package `google.golang.org/grpc/test/bufconn` and if you are interested I can show tests for every type of API.